# Conditions for convergence of moments given uniform convergence of distribution functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

**Setup**: Let $S_n = n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n X_n$ denote a sample mean and let $S_n^*$ denote a stationary bootstrap re-sample of $S_n$. Let $F_n(x)$ denote the cumulative distribution function of $\sqrt{n} S_n$ and let $F_n^*(x)$ denote the cdf of $\sqrt{n} (S_n^* - S_n)$; thus $F_n^*(x)$ is conditional on $X_1, ..., X_n$. Assume $X_n$ is near-epoch-dependent on strong mixing base; assume $\mathbb{E} |X_n|^{2+\delta}$ is finite for some $\delta > 0$; and assume $\mathbb{E} X_n = 0, \forall n$. Then the standard stationary bootstrap result holds, ie:

\begin{equation}
\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |F_n(x) - F_n^*(x)| \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} 0, \: \mathrm{as} \: n \rightarrow \infty
\end{equation}

**Question**: What (if any) additional conditions are needed for:

\begin{equation}
\left| \int_a^b x^{1+\alpha} dF_n^*(x) - \int_a^b x^{1+\alpha} dF_n(x) \right| \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} 0, \: \mathrm{as} \: n \rightarrow \infty ,
\end{equation}

for some $\alpha > 0$, and some arbitrary choice of $a < b$ (possibly $a = -\infty$ and $b = \infty$)?

In words, given uniform convergence in probability of two cdfs (one of them conditional), what additional conditions are necessary to be certain that arbitrary moments also converge in probability?

**Additional Information 1**: I asked a very closely related question on CrossValidated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78631/what-characteristics-of-the-distribution-of-a-test-statistic-can-be-inferred-usi/78779#78779), and was informed (I think) that the moments do converge. However, the answer did not offer any proof, other than an oblique reference to the [uniform convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) in the comments, which actually raised more questions for me than it answered.

**Additional Information 2**: I'm fairly sure the result follows if the convergence in the setup is strengthened to almost sure, see Xiong and Li (2008) "Some Results on the Convergence of Conditional Distributions". However, I'm specifically interested in the case of convergence in probability.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to prove since the moment of your 'limit' random variable depends on n. I assume you mean to do this with absolute values of differences of the moments going to zero. I have not worked this out, but my guess is that it is necessary and sufficient that the sequence of moments is uniformly integrable.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Yes, you are correct - I've fixed the second equation (sorry, the way I had it written before was sloppy). Yes, I suspect uniform integrability might be sufficient, but I'm not confident enough in my knowledge in this area to be sure. I'll offer a bounty in an hour or two to try and elicit a response with proof. :-) ps, thanks for your comment.

Comment: In my opinion, there are some real conceptual problems with this question. I suggest carefully examining standard definitions to ensure you're asking the question you want answered. (1) Random variables converge in probability, functions (or cdfs) don't. So I'm not sure what you mean by the $\overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow}$ notation. (2) How's a conditional distribution differ from, well, any other distribution? One possibility (I really doubt this is what you mean) is that the conditional distribution is a *random* distribution that depends on the conditioning information. Please clarify.

Comment: @WillNelson The convergence in probability notation is appropriate. Are you familiar with bootstrap methods in statistics? That is the motivation for the question. In that literature, the bootstrap cumulative distribution function (evaluated at a point) is conditional on the original sample of data and so is itself a random variable. Hence the convergence in probability. See eg Politis and Romano (1994) "The Stationary Bootstrap" equation 12, or the reference I've given in the section "Additional Information 2" for more detail.

Comment: It seems you are assuming much more setup and structure to this problem than is evident in your Setup section. Why not try to boil the setup down to its essential components and clearly state them in your question? For example, is $F_n$ fixed or random? And $F_n^*$? And I don't think most probability theorists would have any idea how to interpret $F_n^*$ described as a "conditional cdf" without knowing the random variable being conditioned and the $\sigma$-algebra  (or filtration) against which it's being conditioned...

Comment: @WillNelson Honestly, I'm not convinced additional structure beyond what I originally supplied is needed. However, I could be wrong, so I've edited the question to be specifically about the stationary bootstrap re-sample of a sample mean, so that the material should be a bit more familiar to some readers. If you think additional structure beyond my edit is necessary then please let me know what is missing and I'll see what I can do to refine it.

Comment: Colin, You may be right that no additional structure or context is required. But again, the phrase "conditional cdf" is pretty much meaningless without context. (The fact this is a bootstrap setup provides such context.) To strip all the bootstrapping context out, perhaps you're talking about a sequence of fixed cdfs $F_n$ and a sequence of random cdfs $F_n^*$ with $F_n - F_n^*$ converging as you describe and you want to show the moments converge as you describe. So no mention of "conditional cdfs". I'm not sure that's what you want to show, but that at least makes sense to me!

Comment: In your CV post, you mention your motivation here. It's been a while since I thought about bootstrap. Do you have a good reference (preferably online/free) that shows variance or mean is consistently estimated? I'd definitely stare very carefully at those claims and understand their proofs. If you understand those, I suspect you'll be able to answer this question.

Comment: Colin, a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability if and only if every subsequence has a further subsequence which converges to $X$ almost surely.  If you have the result for almost sure convergence, you're done.

Comment: @WillNelson The original paper: Politis, Romano (1994) "The Stationary Bootstrap" is available [here](http://www.econ.ohio-state.edu/dejong/sb.pdf). Also, weaker conditions are proven [here](http://www.econ.ohio-state.edu/dejong/sb.pdf). Another good resource is [here](http://www.unc.edu/~saraswat/teaching/econ870/fall11/JH_01.pdf). The original paper shows consistency of the variance by demonstrating the bootstrap is equivalent (asymptotically) to a kernel function estimator. Unfortunately this approach isn't useful for other moments.

Comment: @WillNelson Also, the convergence I describe in the setup results from building a Berry-Esseen bound for $F_n^*(x)$ and showing that the bound vanishes in $n$ (in probability). Showing that $F_n(x)$ converges to the same Normal is done using a CLT. Not sure if this helps. By the way, the setup you describe stripped of the bootstrapping context is what I was going for. I didn't realize the phrase "conditional cumulative distribution function" would throw people. In hindsight it is perhaps a bit sloppy. Cheers for the heads up.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Yes I agree if the equation I have stated in the setup were almost sure convergence instead of convergence in probability then the result follows - is this what you meant? That's actually what I've used in the paper I'm currently writing. But the assumptions needed for almost sure convergence of the distributions are (currently) stronger than those required for convergence in probability. And I'd rather use the convergence in probability assumption set if I could. Hence the question :-)

Comment: What I am saying is if almost sure convergence of $\sup_x |F_n(x) - F_n^* (x)| \to 0$ implies the result, then convergence in probability of $\sup_x |F_n(x) - F_n^* (x)| \to 0$ implies the result.  This follows from a standard fact about convergence in probability which I mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: Personally, I don't even see how the moments statement (the second formula in original post) will ever follow from the first without some strong assumptions, even if the first uses convergence a.s. What's to stop all the difference in the distributions $F_n$ and $F_n^*$ from being concentrated at arbitrarily large values? For example, let $F_n=0$ and $F_n*$ be the distribution placing weight $1-\epsilon$ on $0$ and $\epsilon$ on $x_n$, which $x_n\to \infty$ very rapidly? The first statement holds, the second won't.

Comment: @WillNelson In whatever setup he is working with, he probably has not just that $E[ X_n^{2 + \delta}]$ is finite, but also uniformly bounded.  In this case, the random variables will be uniformly integrable.  Moreover, the question as currently worded allows for restriction to finite intervals, for which the result is clear.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Good points, especially about the finite interval, which makes it trivial....

Comment: The other assumption is actually also more reasonable than it might appear at first, since this is a resampling technique.  Presumably he is assuming that the $X_n$ are all drawn from the same distribution, in which case the existence of a higher moment implies uniform integrability.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian So what you are saying is that because there exists a subsequence which converges almost surely, we can just use this subsequence in our proof in place of the original sequence, which only converges in probability? If that is the case, then we're nearly done. The only other slight wrinkle is that I'm assuming almost sure convergence in the setup implies that $F_n^*(x)$ converges in distribution to $F(x)$, where $F(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_n(x)$. Is this true? If it is, then uniform integrability (which I'm happy to assume) will be sufficient.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Also, if you write all this up into an answer, I'll award the bounty, answer tick, upvote etc. Cheers.

Comment: Colin, Isn't it true that for fixed finite $a$, $b$, your first formula implies your second formula? That's a trivial fact. It holds when all the bootstrap context is stripped from the setup: if $F_n$ and $F_n^*$ are cdfs (random or not!), then convergence in probability in your first formula is enough to imply convergence in the second (again in prob). I suggest starting by proving that fact. (I don't think that "convergence a.s. implies convergence in probability" has anything to do with anything here. I suspect ChrisJanJigian was also confused by what you were asking. But maybe I'm wrong.)

Comment: Colin, I'm not comfortable enough with your setup to write up a full answer.  What I am saying is that if you are confident that $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |F_n(x) - F_n^*(x)| \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} 0$ implies $|\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{1+\alpha} dF_n^*(x) - \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{1+\alpha} dF_n(x) | \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} 0$ in your setup, then you are done.  It suffices to prove that an arbitrary subsequence of the latter sequence has a further subsequence that converges to zero.  Take a subsequence of the integrals, then look back the the same indices in the CDF.  Take a

Comment: subsequence of that subsequence of CDFs which converges almost surely. The sequence of integrals with the same indices now converges in probability to zero. Since this holds along arbitrary subsequences you are done because convergence in probability is metrizible. I should probably mention that the same trick does not work for a.s. convergence. Regarding your last question, yes a.s. convergence in the setup is much stronger than convergence in distribution to F.

Comment: @WillNelson I agree that choosing fixed finite $a$ and $b$ simplifies the problem greatly since it ensures the integral will exist. However, intuitively I would have thought the type of convergence might still matter. I've already had a go at proving the result using finite $a$ and $b$ but didn't get very far. If you can do such a proof as an answer and Chris does not post anything then I'd definitely be happy to award the bounty for that. Either way, thanks for all your input, it has been very helpful to my thinking.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Thanks for all your discussion Chris - it has been very useful and I've learned a lot. I feel bad that I'm not able to reward it. If you want to edit the question to a setup that you're more comfortable with and then post an answer I'd be happy to award the bounty to that (depending also of course on whether Will posts an answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This addresses the case where $a$ and $b$ are fixed and finite.

Throughout, let $V(\cdot)$ denote the total variation of a function. The domain should be clear from context.

> **Lemma:** Suppose $f$,$F$, and $G$ are functions of bounded variation on $[a,b]$ and suppose $|F(x)-G(x)|\le\epsilon$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Let $M= \sup_{x\in[a,b]} |f(x)|$. Then
>   $$
> \left|\int_a^b f(x) dF(x) - \int_a^b f(x) dG(x)\right|\le \left(2M + V(f)\right)\epsilon.
> $$

**Proof** Integrate by parts:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_a^b f(x) dF(x) - \int_a^b f(x) dG(x) &=& 
 f(b)\left(F(b)-G(b)\right) - f(a)\left(F(a)-G(a)\right) \\ 
& & \ \ - \int_a^b F(x) - G(x)\ df(x).
\end{eqnarray}
Bounding each of the three terms on the right separately gives the result.

> **Corollary:** Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function of bounded variation. Suppose $F_n$ is a sequence of cdfs and $F_n^*$ is a sequence of random cdfs (on some underlying probability space such that the expressions below make sense). If
>   $$
> \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |F_n(x)-F_n^*(x)| \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} 0,
> $$
>   then
>   $$
> \int f(x) dF_n(x) - \int f(x) dF_n^*(x) \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} 0.
> $$

**Proof:** Since $f$ has bounded variation, it is bounded. Let $M$ be such that $|f(x)|\le M$ for all $x$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Let $N$ be such that $n>N$ implies
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |F_n(x) - F_n^*(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2M+V(f)}\right) > 1-\epsilon.
$$
From the lemma, for all $n>N$,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\int f(x)\ dF_n(x) - \int f(x)\ dF_n^*(x)\right|<\epsilon\right) > 1-\epsilon.
$$
The result follows.

**Comment:** The integrals here are over $\mathbb{R}$, but one can take
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^{1+\alpha} \text{ if $x\in[a,b]$}\\
0 \text{ if $x\notin[a,b]$}
\end{cases}
$$
for the original question.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks Will. Next week I'll see if I can extend the ideas here to indefinite integrals. Bounty awarded.